# Get Author/creator of a site/subsite using JSOM OR REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to get the Author of a site using SharePoint REST API.
But I am getting author name as a blank.

Below is the REST Url :

```
https://mysiteName.sharepoint.com/sites/RohitW/_api/web/AllProperties?$expand=Author&$select=Author/Id,Author/Title
```

Output:

[image]

Is there anything I am missing ?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Try it as _api/web/author and check ?

Comment: @GautamSheth I tried this as well. But getting response as `<m:code>-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">User cannot be found.</m:message>`

Comment: I am using SharePoint Online. Is it due to this reason ??

Comment: Strangely, it works if its a subsite. In case of site collection(rootweb), i receive the error you mentioned. Doing some more searching :)

Comment: @GautamSheth Yes. you are right. it is working for subsite only.