# How to retrieve the Creator or Author of a site or any sub site?

Tags: 2013, site-collection, pnp-powershell, sub-site, properties

I cannot find a way to get the creator of a site in a SharePoint site collection (There are more than one administrators), be it in web view or programmatically.

I tried [get-author-creator-of-a-site-subsite-using-jsom-or-rest-api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229732/get-author-creator-of-a-site-subsite-using-jsom-or-rest-api) but seems to work only for (sub-)subsites.
I also tried https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/find-who-created-site-in-sharepoint.html. I would prefer using PnP, but no solution has worked so far.

```
$con = Connect-PnPOnline -ReturnConnection -Url $mySiteUrl -Credentials $myCreds
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Connection $con
Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $web -Property Author
Get-PnPProperty : 'Author' is not a member of 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web'

+ Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $Web -Property Author
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPProperty], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.EnsureProperty
```

I tried including all properties `$web = Get-PnPWeb -Connection $cnx  -Includes allproperties` without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Use Author property of the web object associated with site(remember to change the site URL for yourself):

```
$site = Get-SPSite your site url
$site.RootWeb.Author
$site.Dispose()
```

Reference:

[Programatically determine who created a site collection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92402/programatically-determine-who-created-a-site-collection)

Comment: I forgot to mention we still use SharePoint 2013 On Premise. I used *Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll* taken from [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) maybe not the right assemblies? I also tried with dll from PowerShell Module `SharePointPnPPowerShell2013\3.25.2009.1` (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll) : failure instanciating SharePointOnlineCredentials.

Comment: tried with simple Credentials (not *SharePointOnlineCredentials*) but `$Ctx.Load($Web.Author)`generates an error with Load method complaining about wrong argument number `+ $Ctx.Load($Web.Author)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest`, `$web.Author` being null, I guess.

Comment: Indeed `$Ctx.Load` signature is : OverloadDefinitions: `void Load[T](T clientObject, Params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[System.Func[T,System.Object]][] retrievals)`.

Comment: Realizing now that solutions from [https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/find-who-created-site-in-sharepoint.html](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/02/find-who-created-site-in-sharepoint.html) were the ones I tested and link was in the question!

Comment: This powershell only works with SharePoint online, not for sharepoint server 2013, I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I'm a `Site Collection Administrator` (among others!) and not a `Farm Administrator` hoping I use the right terminology, hence I do not have access to SharePoint Server module which includes `Get-SPSite` Cmdlet AFAIK.

Comment: Should I conclude that one must be a `Farm administrator`? and "close" my question with  `SharePoint-2013 ⇒ as Farm admin + SharePointServer/Get-SPSite`, no possible (yet?) with PnP, nor any other admin role?